# How to create a server side rendered side navigation bar which has multiple sections in my NextJS app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I want to create a server-side rendered side navigation bar on my NextJS application. It has multiple sections with sub-sections as well. The subsections would only be visible on the click of the dropdown arrow adjacent to a particular section (works similar to a dropdown)[image: Should look something like this]

This nav bar would be present in all the pages in my application. SEO is of high priority for me, so ideally I would want all my components to be server side rendered.

Is there a way to achieve this without having to resort to client side rendering?

I have created my component with 'use client' which makes it client side rendered. I have researched on this but wasn't able to find a way to make the same component server-side renderable.
I'm still quite new to nextjs so please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1 Navigation bar :**

> I want to create a server-side rendered side navigation bar on my NextJS application.....  I have researched on this but wasn't able to find a way to make the same component server-side renderable. I'm still quite new to nextjs so please point me in the right direction. Is there a way to achieve this without having to resort to client side rendering?

**Tried :**

> I have created my component with 'use client' which makes it client side rendered.

This is right thing because :

- NextJS says (*read [6](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#when-to-use-server-and-client-components)th link*) that if your components have interactivity(events), or they use browser APIs(localStorage, geolocation, etc.) then you have to make them as Client Side. Because, when this component will be rendered on server it wont get any browser level APIs nor it will understand events because server has no browser, it runs the code.
- Other thing is not all libraries support server-side rendering, hence you have to make such components client side using `use client` (or you get errors like window is undefined etc.).

**Solution :**
You have to keep components that have interactivity as client components. As Navbar component has events hence keep it client side rendered.

**Problem 2 SEO :**

> SEO is of high priority for me

**Solution :**
SEO is implemented on Pages, by exporting `generateMetadata` function in your page.js(if you are using app router) & in pages router using `<Head>` tag provided by NextJS. In pages router, Server-side Rendering for a page, you need to export an async function `getServerSideProps`.

You can combine SSR(server-side rendering) & CSR(client-side rendering) by simply just import your components(some will have `use client`) in page.js(if using app router), & you export your `generateMetadata` function (this takes care of SEO of a page).

***Please Read :***

- **App Router :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app
- **Pages Router :** https://nextjs.org/docs/pages
- **Rendering :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering
- **Server Components :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components
- **Client Components :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components
- **When to use Server and Client Components?** : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#when-to-use-server-and-client-components

Pages Router :

- **Rendering :** https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/rendering
- **Metadata :** https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing#metadata
- `<Head>` : https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/head

> ***If you still have doubts, leave a comment.***